# Xamarin.Forms C# Picker and Lists of Tuples not displaying anything

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem is in a Xamarin.Forms with C# for Android Project.
I am trying to display a List of Tuples in a Picker to choose one of them. I am using the `(int ID, string Name)` notation of Tuples in the ObservableCollection `ObservableCollection<(int ID, string Name)> BLA => new ObservableCollection<(int ID, string Name)>();`.

Sadly neither `<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding BLA}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>` nor `<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding BLA}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>` display the Name Property of the Tuple in the selection popup.

The "old" way like `ObservableCollection<Tuple<int,string>> BLAT => new ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string>>();` works fine with `<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding BLAT}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>`.

Is the first way of Tuples not yet supported by Xamarin or do I have to setup something first?

Comment: I don't think data binding works with anonymous types like the first example.  You can use the Tuple class to achieve the same thing

Comment: Thanks, I thought since C# 7 ```Tuple<int, string>``` should be the same as ```(int ID, string)``` as described in this aritcle: [C# 7.0: Tuples Explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/august/essential-net-csharp-7-0-tuples-explained?source=docs)

Comment: @LarsR Maybe, we look forward to.

Answer (score 1):

A [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource) can be also populated with data by using data binding to bind its ItemsSource property to an IList collection.

Note that each item in the ItemsSource collection is of type object, and so must be cast to a string for display.

Usually, I create one model class that contains some properties, to binding in xaml.

```
 public class model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<model> listdata { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listdata = new ObservableCollection<model>()
        {
            new model(){Id=1,Name="model 1"},
            new model(){Id=2,Name="model 2"},
            new model(){Id=3,Name="model 3"},
            new model(){Id=4,Name="model 4"}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

When binding to a list of objects, the Picker must be told which property to display from each object. This is achieved by setting the `ItemDisplayBinding` property to the required property from each object. In the code examples above, the Picker is set to display each `model.Name` property value.

```
<Picker
            Title="Select a model"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding listdata}"
            TitleColor="Red" />
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to use custom class, you can use Dictionary<TKey,TValue> to store data.

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{      
    public static  Dictionary<string, int> colors { get; }= new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { "model1", 6 },
        { "model2", 1 },
        { "model3", 2 },
        { "model4", 3 },
        { "model5", 4 },
        { "model6", 5 }
    };
    public List<string> Colors { get; } = colors.Keys.ToList();

  
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

  <Picker
            Title="Select a model"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"
            TitleColor="Red" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think you are missing my point here. I explicitly do not want to use a custom class for my display since the data is just throwaway data and a tuple with few Items will be more efficient. The only reason I want to use the ```(int ID, string Name)``` notation is the ability to troubleshoot will be better with named Items than  always using Item1 and Item2.

Comment: @LarsR I think Xamarin don't support the first way that you mentioned, if you don't want to use custom class, you can consider to use Dictionary, please see my update.